# php echo adding on "0');</script>" to the end of the output

Tags: javascript, php, apache, echo

I run a local server I am working on and php echo appears to be freaking out. This is the error:

```
echo "<script>console.log('test');</script>";
```

yields

```
<script>console.log('test');</script>;0')</script>
```

when I "view page source" of the webpage. In the page itself, this shows up as just `0');` and the `console.log()` appears to be working just fine. If I change one of these to remove all javascript and just do something like

```
echo "testing";
```

what shows up is:

```
testing0');</script>
```

when I write a new echo it works fine, when I have tried making new pages, they also work fine, when I view it in safari (I regularly use chrome) this problem persists. This problem occurs each time I echo a script, but when echoing something else it behaves normally. Only if I change an existing echo to plain text does it still append the `;0')</script>`, when I write a new echo that writes a script it works just fine.

If I add `die();` after any echo statements, that one (and that one only) lacks the `;0')</script>` all those above it still have it at the end.

What the heck did I do to cause this?

info:
I am using the default apache install on mac and php version 5.5.36. Feel free to ask me clarifying questions and if need be I can post the full php file on github.

Thanks in advance,

Lewis

Edited for clarity.

Comment: What if you type `echo "testing"; die();`? It seems like you have an extra `echo` farther down.

Comment: You are either `echo`ing `0')</script>` father down, or you have `0')</script>` outside of PHP tags father down the page. Show more code please.

Comment: I guess I should have been more clear, this happens on multiple lines wherever I have `echo "<script></script>";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I feel pretty dumb, I was indeed spitting out `;0')</script>` after each and every echo, because all of my `console.log()`s came in pairs and the second one always looked something like this:

```
echo "\n<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n    console.debug('".'  '+gettype($sql_peices)."');\n</script>";
```

and the plus in there was causing the issue, I should have:

```
echo "\n<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n    console.debug('".'  '.gettype($sql_peices)."');\n</script>";
```

with a period. I have no idea when or how I put that in there, but now everything is working perfectly.

Comment: To make this helpful to the community - would you consider updating the question to include this snippet of code so that the answer becomes relevant to the question?

Comment: sure, no problem. should I just include it in the question?

Comment: Maybe just update the first code block to include it.